# Populate a Django Model from List of Lists

Tags: django, django-models

I have a list of lists. I'd like to populate a Model with that data.

```
my_list = [['January', 'February', 'March'], [10, 20, 30], [2, 4, 6]]

The Model I's like to build is:

MyModel(models.Model):
    month = models.Charfield(maxlength=12) # This is my_list[0]
    sales = models.DecimalField() # This is my_list[1]
    expenses = models.DecimalField() # This is my_list[2]
```

Please excuse any typos. I typed this out from memory. I am looking for the general principle on how to generate a model from a list of lists. I'd like to avoid storing lists in a single db entry (by using JSON, etc.) and instead would like each db entry to hold a single value. In other words my Month row would have a separate column for January, February, and March.

Thanks in advnace!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) for creating all records using one query:

```
objects = []
for month, sales, expenses in zip(*my_list):
    objects.append(MyModel(
        month=month,
        sales=sales,
        expenses=expenses
    ))
MyModel.objects.bulk_create(objects)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Quick question, does this for loop go into the model itself after the field definitions? Would it go into a function that is then called? Using zip and bulk_create is very clean but I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: From docs for bulk_create: The model’s save() method will not be called, and the pre_save and post_save signals will not be sent. So if you have custom save method you can create models in for loop and save it in for loop. But it will work slower than bulk_create because it will hit database for each new model.